# in javascript is it possible to assign a arithmetic operand to a variable?

Tags: javascript, variables, math, operators

I know I can simply use an if else statement to have the math done for me, and could even create a function that could be called either way depending on the need, but I am trying to based on math simply store either + or - as a variable so it can execute

for example

```
plusOrMinus = +

5 + plusOrMinus + 5 = 10
```

Comment: well yes and you can use `eval()` but its quite dangerous.

Comment: @Mahan I would love to see an example with `eval()` and hear the reasoning for why it's "dangerous"

Comment: I have heard people say eval() is dangerous, but I know people can inline edit javascript with modern browsers; and whatnot, I just see no danger of it other than someone injecting something into their specific browser.

Comment: well for me using eval() is a function that you must not use as much as possible especially when your'e evaluating a user input

Comment: as a side note to the question, I am using this for movement in a gamequery game from a new user created position to the old position to with a loop create the illusion of movement: user moves object 100 px to the left, 100 px above, in order to go to the initial position I could simply create a loop that would adjust it accordingly and thought "hmm, wonder if I can store plus or minus variable depending on if the x position is greater or less than the initial position and same for the y position" more of a food for thought programming problem than anything

Comment: @g00ch—in that case just have a *sign* or *direction* parameter that is either +1 or -1, then multiply your final value by the sign. In a game, usually performance matters and *eval* is slow (though perhaps not slow enough to matter in your case).

Comment: @g00ch—regarding *eval*, it is strongly warned against because it was widely misused in early scripting where the language wasn't understood, e.g. `eval('document.all(' + elementName + ')')`. There is nothing inherently "evil" or dangerous, it's just considered poor practice as the alternatives are faster, less to write and have fewer side effects (from memory, *eval* can have scope issues but I 'm a little rusty on that because I almost never use it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what kind of situation you're in, but wouldn't multiplying by 1 or -1 suffice?

```
plusOrMinus = 1
5 + (plusOrminus * 5) = 10

plusOrMinus = -1
5 + (plusOrminus * 5) = 0
```

Comment: Seems to me that `5 - 5 = 0`, not `-10`.

Answer (score 2):

No, but it is possible to create a function that wraps the given operator(s):

```
function add(a, b) { return a + b };
function sub(a, b) { return a - b };

var op = add;  // look, functions are just objects!
op(5, 5) // -> 10
var op = sub;
op(7, 3) // -> 4
```

Well, how does this help us? Just expand it!

```
function fold (arr, fn) {
    var r = arr[0];
    for (var i = 1; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
        r = fn(r, arr[i]);
    }
    return r;
}
fold([1,2,3], add) // -> 6
```

Answer (score 1):

You can store 1 or -1, and multiply, like this:

```
var plusOrMinus;
var Result;

plusOrMinus = 1;

Result = (5 + 5) * plusOrMinus; // 10

plusOrMinus = -1;

Result = (5 + 5) * plusOrMinus; // -10
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably need eval()

```
plusOrMinus  = '+'

eval(5+plusorMinus+5);
```